# Youtube Livestream - ffmpeg error: av_interleaved_write_frame(): End of File

Tags: linux, error-handling, ffmpeg, live-streaming, raspivid

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B (OS: Raspian) to livestream an attached camera feed to YouTube using the following command in a python script(I removed the livestream secret key):

`raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[My Secret Key]> /home/Desktop/Livestream_Logs/Output_Runthrough".txt 2>&1`

However, I am running into a problem where the livestream cuts out at random times (usually after an hour) and the command terminates due to the following error: **av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe**

I am new to the ffmpeg command and live-streaming in general, so please go easy on me for I do not know what I am doing wrong with this command, nor do I understand all its arguments! This is a Christmas project I am working on, and I copied this command from [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/live-stream-youtube-raspberry-pi/).

Below is the output log from running the command. There were over 60,000 frames in the log so I removed most lines to save space, but included some samples; the bitrate and speed remained relatively the same throughout the command's execution:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.5-0+deb11u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt2 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, s16le, from '/dev/zero':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Input #1, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[My Secret Key]':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1200k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
[flv @ 0x130e5f0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[h264 @ 0x1308e30] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     188kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=3202.0kbits/s speed=0.948x    
frame=   25 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=     582kB time=00:00:00.97 bitrate=4892.9kbits/s speed=0.966x    
frame=   38 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=     909kB time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=5012.3kbits/s speed=0.983x    
frame=   50 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    1219kB time=00:00:01.99 bitrate=5001.6kbits/s speed=0.988x    
frame=   63 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    1594kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=5255.3kbits/s speed=0.983x    
frame=   76 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    1855kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=5064.6kbits/s speed=0.99x    
   
frame= 2144 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   52465kB time=00:01:25.75 bitrate=5012.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2157 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   52755kB time=00:01:26.24 bitrate=5011.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2170 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   53101kB time=00:01:26.76 bitrate=5013.8kbits/s speed=   1x     

frame=25690 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=  628697kB time=00:17:07.57 bitrate=5012.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=25703 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=  628980kB time=00:17:08.08 bitrate=5011.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=25715 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=  629295kB time=00:17:08.59 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x     

frame=58274 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 1426073kB time=00:38:50.93 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=58287 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 1426391kB time=00:38:51.44 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=58299 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 1426707kB time=00:38:51.95 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x     

frame=94289 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 2307471kB time=01:02:51.54 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=94302 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 2307767kB time=01:02:52.04 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=94315 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 2308071kB time=01:02:52.56 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    

frame=128044 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 3133566kB time=01:25:21.74 bitrate=5012.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=128057 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 3133823kB time=01:25:22.25 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=128069 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 3134109kB time=01:25:22.72 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=0.996x    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): End of file
[flv @ 0x130e5f0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x130e5f0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[My Secret Key]: End of file
frame=128069 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize= 3134109kB time=01:25:22.74 bitrate=5011.9kbits/s speed=0.996x    
video:3126661kB audio:1307kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.196311%
[aac @ 0x130ed10] Qavg: 65536.000
Conversion failed!
```

As stated before the command I am using is from [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/live-stream-youtube-raspberry-pi/). However, they are using avconv instead of ffmpeg, but since avconv would not work on my raspberry pi, I switched out "avconv" for "ffmpeg" and kept all the same flags.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?